# How do I format an integer as a time using D3.js or nvD3.js

Tags: d3.js, graphing, nvd3.js

I have hours in an array 1 - 24 as integers just like that. I want to know how to format the x axis for that those values are displayed as times 12:00 am - 12:00 pm. I cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.

```
var hours = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
];
var timeformat = d3.time.format('%I:%M%p');

var now = new Date()
now.setHours(hours[15]);
now.setMinutes(0);

var time = timeformat(now); // 04:00PM
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjfX4/4/)

Comment: thanks I'm actually using nvd3 (a light wrapper above d3) here is my tick function.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%I:%M%p')(new Date(d)); }); but this does not seems to work.